# Conditional linebreak in align environment

Tags: equations, line-breaking, align, conditionals

I have a large document to typeset in two different page formats. Some of the equation lines are too long in the small format so I wanted to break some equation lines conditioned on whether the macro `\usesmallformat` is defined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Uncomment for small format - doesn't work, however
% \newcommand{\usesmallformat}{1}
% \setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \|(I-K^i)(I-F^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)} \nonumber \\
%
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \left(\|(B - C^i)(I - D^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)}
{\ifdefined\usesmallformat \right. \nonumber\\ \fi}
%
\label{eq:One}
{\ifdefined\usesmallformat &\quad\ \fi}
+
{\ifdefined\usesmallformat \left. \fi}
\|(I - D^i)(I - S^i) u \|_{V(\Omega)} \right).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I would like the second line of the align environment to be broken at the `+`-sign in the small format. Only the last line should be numbered.
Also I would like to avoid duplicating formula code. Setting the `align` environment in two versions and surrounding them with the `\ifdefined` would work, but leads to code bloat and is harder to maintain in the future.

If I uncomment the two lines at the beginning of the document, however, I get `Missing } inserted \end{align}` and some follow-up errors.

Do you have any idea how to achieve the desired effect?

PS: I've read about the breqn package, but I can't use it because it conflicts with some other package that I have to include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better and simpler to use the mechanisms provided by `etoolbox`, where you can set up a `toggle` (or alternatively a `bool`).  The following makes your example work, but I don't like the coding and will give another approach below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\newtoggle{smallformat}
\settoggle{smallformat}{false} %set to true or false as required
\iftoggle{smallformat}{\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \|(I-K^i)(I-F^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)} \nonumber \\
%
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \left(\|(B - C^i)(I - D^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)}
\iftoggle{smallformat}{\right. \nonumber\\}{}
%
\label{eq:One}
\iftoggle{smallformat}{&\quad\ }{}
+
\iftoggle{smallformat}{\left. }{}
\|(I - D^i)(I - S^i) u \|_{V(\Omega)} \right).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The addition to your code declares a new toggle `smallformat`, and in this case initially sets it to `false`.  You then have the `\iftoggle{smallformat}{truecase}{falsecase}` for use in your code.

Now to how I would prefer to code this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,etoolbox}

\newtoggle{smallformat}
\settoggle{smallformat}{true}
\iftoggle{smallformat}{\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}}{}

\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:One}
  \begin{split}
    A &\leqslant
    \sum_{i = 0}^L \norm{(I-K^i)(I-F^i)u}_{V(\Omega)} \\
    &\leqslant
    \sum_{i = 0}^L \bigl(\norm{B - C^i)(I - D^i)u}_{V(\Omega)}
    \iftoggle{smallformat}{\eqbreak}{}
    + \|(I - D^i)(I - S^i) u \|_{V(\Omega)} \bigr).
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Your display is a single equation spread over several lines, therefore `equation` with an internal `split` is more appropriate as you only want one equation number.

Use of `\left...\right` should be restricted as much as possible.  Using `\bigl...\bigr` and their cousins makes coding in your example easier.  It also avoids the situation where all the tall material is on just one line, which in the narrow version would result in parentheses of different sizes.

The optional line break is via a new command `\eqbreak` that I find very useful in displays.  It takes an optional argument saying how much the next line should be indented.  By default this is set to `\qquad` = `2em`, but e.g. `\eqbreak[4]` will give twice as much.

I have used `mathtools` to set up a `\norm` command form your `\|...\|`, this should give better spacing around these terms, without something like this LaTeX does not which `\|` is a left delimiter.

Finally I prefer `\leqslant` to `\leq`.

Narrow output:

[image: Sample narrow output]

Answer (score 5):

You need to not insert `{}` around the alignment markup in the small case, and you need to not put `&` in the middle of the `\if` in the other case, so..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

 \newcommand{\usesmallformat}{1}
 \setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sformat{%
\relax\ifdefined\usesmallformat\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \|(I-K^i)(I-F^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)} \nonumber \\
%
&\leq
\sum_{i = 0}^L \left(\|(B - C^i)(I - D^i)u\|_{V(\Omega)}
\sformat{\right. \nonumber\\}
%
\label{eq:One}
\sformat{&\quad\ }
+
\sformat{\left.}
\|(I - D^i)(I - S^i) u \|_{V(\Omega)} \right).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I like it because it works without additional packages, and it solves my problem just fine. I accepted Andrew Swann's answer though because I learned even more from it.